# Nested for loop that will create 8x8 grid with JButton for each tile for game of Othello

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, nested-for-loop

I need to create a 8x8 grid where each tile is a `JButton` using two nested for loops. I’ve tried and tried but can’t get it done.
Needed for a game of Reversi (Othello) assignment.

Comment: Please read the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on a question. [tag:tiles] is for something completely different, and the pop-up for [tag:grid] explicitly advises ***not*** to use it (ever). For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a nifty tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that will take you through the steps of creating a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Here's a GUI with an 8 x 8 grid of `JButtons`.

[image: Othello GUI]

The first thing I did was make a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a `JFrame`.  The `JFrame` methods must be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for most of my Swing applications.

I created a `JPanel`.  The `JPanel` uses a `GridLayout` to lay out the 64 `JButtons` I created.

Swing components should always be constructed in a `JPanel`.  A `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout` that allows you to place up to nine `JPanels` on the `JFrame`.  Even though it's possible, you should never place any Swing components other than `JPanels` or `JScrollPanes` directly on a `JFrame`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class OthelloGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new OthelloGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Othello GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 8));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        for (int index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(64, 64));
            panel.add(button);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```